# IntelliJ does not recognize "let"

Tags: intellij-idea

IntelliJ does not recognize when I declare a variable with `let` in javascript.

*It recognizes `var` and `const` just fine.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**File** > **Settings** (Ctrl + Alt + S) > **Languages & Frameworks** > **Javascript**

Change JavaScript language version to `ECMAScript 6` or higher